# How to find rows that have only one value in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to find rows from table 1 that are joining with table 2 and have all rows same in table 2.

Example:

Row with id 4 in table2 is not valid because have different values in table1 (value1, value)
Row with id 5 in table2 is valid because have same values in table1 (value3)

```
table1
+----+--------+----------+
| id |table2Id| value    |
+----+--------+----------+
| 1  | 4      |value1    |
| 2  | 4      |value2    |
| 3  | 5      |value3    |
| 4  | 5      |value3    |
| 5  | 5      |value3    |
+----+--------+----------+

table2
+----+
| id |
+----+
| 4  |
| 5  |
+----+
```

Comment: We shouldn't be providing solutions to  question that demonstrates no effort to solve the problem.

Comment: @nicomp showing attempts isn't a reason to *not* answer. It can, however, be a reason to downvote as it is normally an indication that the OP hasn't performed any research. But down votes and close votes are 2 distinctly different actions and though they share some reasons for both, a lack of evidence of attempts/research is not one of them.

Comment: @Larnu I respectfully disagree.

Comment: Could you direct me to the Close Reason that says "This question doesn't show any attempts", and I'll VTC then @nicomp . Unfortunately, I don't see it in my options.

Comment: @Larnu It's under "Community specific", then "needs debugging information."

Comment: That doesn't say "The question doesn't show any attempts" @nicomp . The OP isn't looking for debugging help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why a `join` is necessary.  You can just use the information in `table1`:

```
select t1.*
from (select t1.*,
             min(value) over (partition by table2id) as min_value,
             max(value) over (partition by table2id) as max_value
      from table1 t1
     ) t1
where min_value = max_value;
```

Or use `not exists`:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1
                  from table1 tt1
                  where tt1.table2id = t1.table2id and
                        tt1.value = t1.value
                 );
```

In either case, you can join to `table2` if you need to for filtering or for other columns, but based on the information in your question the `join` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT max(table2Id) as Id,value 
FROM table1 
GROUP BY value 
HAVING COUNT(value)=1) JOIN table2 on table1.Id = table2.Id
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
Select t1.* from table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t1.table2Id = t2.id
```